# Problem $u_t - u_{xx} = f(x)$ in $\mathbb{R} \times (0,+\infty)$ with $f$ given

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, heat-equation

Consider the following problem:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
u_t - u_{xx} & = & f(x), \ \ \mathbb{R} \times (0,+\infty)\\
u(x,0) & = & e^{-|x|}, \ \ \mathbb{R}
\end{array}\right.$$
with
$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
e^{-x}, & x > 0\\ 
0, & x \leq 0. 
\end{array}\right.$$

Note that
$$\mathcal{F}(u_t) = \mathcal{F}(u_{xx} + f(x)) = -\xi^2\mathcal{F}(u) + \mathcal{F}(f).$$

In addition, we also have
$$\mathcal{F}(f) = \dfrac{1-i\xi }{1 + \xi^2}.$$

So, we will analyze the problem:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\widehat{u_t}(\xi,t) & = & -\xi^2\widehat{u}(\xi,t) + \dfrac{1-i\xi }{1 + \xi^2}\\
\widehat{u}(\xi,0) & = & \dfrac{\sqrt{2/\pi}}{\xi^2 + 1},
\end{array}\right.$$

because
$$\mathcal{F}(e^{-|x|}) = \dfrac{\sqrt{2/\pi}}{\xi^2 + 1}.$$

Now, for every $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$, we can explicitly solve the ODE, getting:
$$\widehat{u}(\xi,t) = Ce^{-\xi^2t} + \dfrac{1-i\xi}{\xi^2(1 + \xi^2)},$$
where $C$ is a constant. From the initial condition, it follows that
$$C = \dfrac{\sqrt{2/\pi}}{\xi^2 + 1} - \dfrac{1-i\xi}{\xi^2(1 + \xi^2)}.$$
So it follows that
\begin{eqnarray}
\widehat{u}(\xi,t) & = & \dfrac{\sqrt{2/\pi}}{\xi^2 + 1}e^{-\xi^2t} - \dfrac{1-i\xi}{\xi^2(1 + \xi^2)}e^{-\xi^2t} + \dfrac{1-i\xi}{\xi^2(1 + \xi^2)}\\ 
& = & \dfrac{\sqrt{2/\pi}}{\xi^2 + 1}e^{-\xi^2t} + \dfrac{1-i\xi}{\xi^2(1 + \xi^2)}[1-e^{-\xi^2t}].
\end{eqnarray}

**Doubt:** How do I return the $u$ function? I tried to calculate the inverse Fourier transform but I couldn't.

Comment: [This method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4313457/problem-u-t-u-xx-et-in-mathbbr-times-0-infty/4313583#4313583) is easier.

Comment: The problem is that I have been using the Fourier transform, even though I know it's not the best method.