# How to solve the following Poisson equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve the following Poisson equation $$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=x^2+4xy  \text{ for }  x^2+y^2<4\\
u(x,y)=-2 \text{ for } x^2+y^2=4$$

I know how to solve homogenous Laplace equation but I have no idea how to solve can you help

Comment: Do you know about separation of variables method?

Comment: @Yalikesifulei..i know

Comment: Try looking for solution in form $u = u_1 + u_2$, where $u_1$ is solution of $(u_1)_{xx} + (u_1)_{yy} = 0$, $u_1(x,y) = -2, x^2 + y^2 = 4$ and $u_2$ is some solution of  $(u_2)_{xx} + (u_2)_{yy} = x^2 + 4xy$ and $u_2(x,y) = 0, x^2 + y^2 = 4$. It seems easy to make an ansatz about form of $u_2$. Maybe, further split into two problems with r.h.s. $x^2$ and $4xy$ will be needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x = r \cos \varphi, y = r \sin \varphi$ for $r \in [0, 2]$ and $\phi \in [0, 2\pi)$. Then for $v(r, \varphi) = u(r \cos \varphi, r \sin \varphi)$: $$u_{xx} + u_{yy} = \frac{1}{r^2} \left(r^2 v_{rr} + r v_r + v_{\varphi \varphi} \right) = r^2 \left( \cos^2 \varphi + 4 \cos \varphi \sin \varphi\right) \Leftrightarrow \\
\Leftrightarrow r^2 v_{rr} + r v_r + v_{\varphi \varphi} = r^4 \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\cos2\varphi + 4 \cos \varphi \sin \varphi\right)
$$ and $v(2, \varphi) = -2$.
Let's look for a solution in form of $v(r, \varphi) = v_0 (r, \varphi) + v_1 (r, \varphi) + v_2 (r, \varphi)$, where
$$
\begin{cases}
r^2 (v_0)_{rr} + r (v_0)_r + (v_0)_{\varphi \varphi} = 0 \\
v_0(2, \varphi) = -2 \\
r^2 (v_1)_{rr} + r (v_1)_r + (v_1)_{\varphi \varphi} = \frac{1}{2}r^4 \\
v_1(2, \varphi) = 0 \\
r^2 (v_2)_{rr} + r (v_2)_r + (v_2)_{\varphi \varphi} = r^4 
\cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\cos2\varphi + 4 \cos \varphi \sin \varphi \right)\\
v_2(2, \varphi) = 0
\end{cases} 
$$

Let's make an ansatz that $v_1(r, \varphi) = f_1(r)$ and $v_2(r, \varphi) = f_2(r) \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\cos2\varphi + 4 \cos \varphi \sin \varphi \right)$. Then
$$
\begin{cases}
r^2 f_1''(r) + r f_1'(r) = \frac{1}{2} r^4 \\
f(2) = 0 \\
\end{cases} \Leftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
r f_1''(r) + f_1'(r) = \frac{1}{2}r^3 \\
f_1(2) = 0
\end{cases} \Leftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
\left(r f_1'(r) \right)' = \frac{1}{2}r^3 \\
f_1(2) = 0
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \\
\Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
f_1(r) = \frac{1}{32}r^4 + c_1 \ln r + c_2 \\
f_1(2) = 0
\end{cases}
$$
As $f_1$ must be defined for $r=0$, $c_1 = 0$ and from $f_1(2) = 0$ $c_2 = -\frac{1}{2}$, so $v_1(r, \varphi) = f_1(r) = \frac{1}{32}r^4 - \frac{1}{2}
$.
Now let's take a look at $v_2$. As $$(v_2)_{\varphi \varphi} = f_2(r) \cdot
\left(\frac{1}{2}\cos2\varphi + 4 \cos \varphi \sin \varphi\right)_{\varphi \varphi} = f_2(r) \cdot (-4) \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\cos2\varphi + 4 \cos \varphi \sin \varphi\right)$$
we get
$$
\begin{cases}
r^2 f_2''(r) + r f_2'(r) - 4 f_2(r) = r^4 \\
f_2(2) = 0
\end{cases} \Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
f_2(r) = \frac{1}{12}r^4 + \frac{c_1}{r^2} + c_2 r^2 \\
f_2(2) = 0
\end{cases}
$$
Again, as $f_2$ must be defined for $r=0$, $c_1 = 0$ and from $f_2(2) = 0$ we get $c_2 = -\frac{1}{3}$, so $f_2(r) = \frac{1}{12}r^4 - \frac{1}{3}r^2$.

Finally, $v_0$ is easy to find with standard methods (seperation of variables). Letting $v_0(r, \varphi) = f(r) \cdot g(\varphi)$ leads to
$$
v_0(r, \varphi) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n \left(
C_n \cos n\varphi + D_n \sin n\varphi
\right)
$$
As $v_0(2, \varphi) = -2 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^n \left(
C_n \cos n\varphi + D_n \sin n\varphi
\right)$, we conclude that $C_0 = -2, D_0 = 0$, $C_n = D_n = 0, n \geq 1$, so $v_0(r, \varphi) = -2$. Finally,
$$
v(r, \varphi) = -2 + \left(\frac{1}{32}r^4 - \frac{1}{2}\right) +
\left( \frac{1}{12}r^4 - \frac{1}{3}r^2 \right) \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\cos2\varphi + 4 \cos \varphi \sin \varphi\right) = \\ =
-\frac{5}{2} + \frac{1}{32}r^4 + \frac{1}{24}r^4 \cos2\varphi + \frac{1}{3}r^4 \cos \varphi \sin \varphi - \frac{1}{6}r^2 \cos2\varphi - \frac{4}{3}r^2 \cos \varphi \sin \varphi = \\ = - \frac{5}{2} + \frac{1}{12}r^4 \left(\frac{3}{8} + 
\frac{1}{2}\cos 2\varphi\right) + \frac{1}{3}r^4 \cos \varphi \sin \varphi - 
\frac{1}{3} r^2 \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\cos2\varphi\right) + \frac{1}{6}r^2 - \frac{4}{3}r^2 \cos \varphi \sin \varphi = \\ =
- \frac{5}{2} + \frac{1}{12} r^4 \left(\cos^2 \varphi - \frac{1}{8}\right) + \frac{1}{3}r^4 \cos \varphi \sin \varphi - \frac{1}{3}r^2\cos^2\varphi + \frac{1}{6}r^2 - \frac{4}{3}r^2 \cos \varphi \sin \varphi
$$
Remembering that  $x = r \cos \varphi, y = r \sin \varphi$, we finally get
$$
u(x, y) = -\frac{5}{2} - \frac{1}{96}(x^2 + y^2)^2 + \frac{1}{12} (x^2+y^2)x^2 + \frac{1}{3} (x^2+y^2)xy - \frac{1}{3}x^2 + \frac{1}{6}(x^2+y^2) -\frac{4}{3}xy
$$

Comment: thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can just set up a discretized linear equation system.

Make ansatz of truncated power series expansion $$u(x,y) = \sum_{\forall i,j \in\{0,\cdots,N\}} c_{ij}x^iy^j$$

Vectorize $c_{ij}$ lexicographically. Implement $\bf D$ as $\{0,1,\cdots N-1\}$ 1 step off-diagonal matrix. Example for 6th degree polynomial :

$${\bf D} = \left[\begin{array}{lllllll}&1&&&&&\\&&2&&&&\\&&&3&&&\\&&&&4&&\\&&&&&5&\\&&&&&&6\\&&&&&&\end{array}\right]$$

Now we can construct 2D partial differentiators like so:

$${\bf D_x = ({\bf I}\otimes {\bf D})}\\{\bf D_y = (D\otimes I)}$$

Now set up boundary conditions. We can sample uniformly $$x+yi = 2\exp(2\pi i k/N), \forall k \in\{0,\cdots,N-1\}$$

Remains to do is to build equation system and solve it. Here is what a solution can look like (the blue circles are the linearly spaced points used to ensure boundary conditions are followed) :

[image]

Just for verification purposes now that we have an exact solution by @Yalikesifulei here is a truncated representation of the numerical solution (any number abs val $<10^{-10}$ has been set to $0$) :

$$\left[\begin{array}{lllll}-2.500&0&0.166667&0&-0.01041666\\0&-1.3333&0&0.333333&0\\-0.166667&0&0.06249999&0&0\\0&0.33333&0&0&0\\0.07291666&0&0&0&0\end{array}\right]$$

The three trickiest coefficients which we may not see straight from ocular inspection are the same are

for $y^4$ :

$1/12-1/96 = 0.07916666...$

and $x^4$ :

$-1/96 = -0.010416666...$

and for $x^2y^2$ :

$1/12-2/96 = 0.0625$

Comment: thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

It is beneficial to adopt the plane polar coordinates for this problem. One has
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial{r}}\Bigg(r\frac{\partial}{\partial{r}}\psi\Bigg) +\frac{1}{r^{2}}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial{\varphi}^{2}}\psi=r^{2}[\cos^{2}\varphi+2\sin2\varphi], \quad \psi(2, \varphi)=-2.
\end{align}
The solution to the homogenous equation obeys
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial{r}}\Bigg(r\frac{\partial}{\partial{r}}\psi_{h}\Bigg) +\frac{1}{r^{2}}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial{\varphi}^{2}}\psi_{h}=0
\end{align}
We let
\begin{align}
\psi_{h}(r, \varphi)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\hat\psi_{h}^{(n)}(r)e^{in\varphi},
\end{align}
so that
\begin{align}
r^{2}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial{r}^{2}}\hat\psi_{h}^{(n)}+r\frac{\partial}{\partial{r}}\hat\psi_{h}^{(n)}-n^{2}\hat\psi_{h}^{(n)}=0.
\end{align}
This is a standard Euler equation which has the solution
\begin{align}
\hat\psi_{h}^{(n)}(r)=C_{h, +}^{(n)}r^{n}+C_{h, -}^{(n)}r^{-n}.
\end{align}
Hence
\begin{align}
\psi_{h}(r, \varphi)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}[C_{h, +}^{(n)}r^{n}+C_{h, -}^{(n)}r^{-n}]\frac{e^{in\varphi}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}.
\end{align}
Now we consider the inhomogeneous part, i.e. the particular solution
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial{r}}\Bigg(r\frac{\partial}{\partial{r}}\psi_{p}\Bigg) +\frac{1}{r^{2}}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial{\varphi}^{2}}\psi_{p}=r^{2}[\cos^{2}\varphi+2\sin2\varphi], \quad \psi(2, \varphi)=-2.
\end{align}
Again we Fourier expand
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial{r}}\Bigg(r\frac{\partial}{\partial{r}}\psi_{p}^{(n)}\Bigg) -\frac{n^{2}}{r^{2}}\psi_{p}^{(n)}=r^{2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}d\varphi[\cos^{2}\varphi+2\sin2\varphi]\frac{e^{-in\varphi}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}.
\end{align}
We have
\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}d\varphi[\cos^{2}\varphi+2\sin2\varphi]\frac{e^{-in\varphi}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{4}[2\delta_{n, 0}+[1-4i]\delta_{n, 2}+[1+4i]\delta_{n, -2}].
\end{align}
Hence the "non-trivial" modes satisfy
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial{r}^{2}}\psi_{p}^{(0)}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial{r}}\psi_{p}^{(0)}=&r^{2}\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2},\\
\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial{r}^{2}}\psi_{p}^{(2)}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial{r}}\psi_{p}^{(2)} -\frac{4}{r^{2}}\psi_{p}^{(2)}=&r^{2}\frac{[1-4i]\sqrt{2\pi}}{4},\\
\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial{r}^{2}}\psi_{p}^{(-2)}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial{r}}\psi_{p}^{(-2)} -\frac{4}{r^{2}}\psi_{p}^{(-2)}=&r^{2}\frac{[1+4i]\sqrt{2\pi}}{4}.
\end{align}
We let
\begin{align}
\psi_{p}^{(0)}=&\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{32}r^{4},\\
\psi_{p}^{(2)}=&\frac{[1-4i]\sqrt{2\pi}}{48}r^{4},\\
\psi_{p}^{(-2)}=&\frac{[1+4i]\sqrt{2\pi}}{48}r^{4}.
\end{align}
It follows
\begin{align}
\psi_{p}(r, \varphi)=&\frac{r^{4}}{8}\Bigg[\frac{1}{4}+\frac{2}{3}\cos(2\varphi)+\frac{8}{3}\sin(2\varphi)\Bigg].
\end{align}
The general solution is thus given by
\begin{align}
\psi(r, \varphi)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}[C_{h, +}^{(n)}r^{n}+C_{h, -}^{(n)}r^{-n}]\frac{e^{in\varphi}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}+\psi_{p}(r, \varphi).
\end{align}
The boundary conditions dictate
\begin{align}
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}[C_{h, +}^{(n)}2^{n}+C_{h, -}^{(n)}2^{-n}]\frac{e^{in\varphi}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}+\psi_{p}(2, \varphi)=-2.
\end{align}
We multiply by $\frac{e^{-in\varphi}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ an integrate over $2\pi$, so that
\begin{align}
C_{h, +}^{(n)}2^{n}+C_{h, -}^{(n)}2^{-n}+\psi_{p}^{(0)}(2)\delta_{n, 0}+\psi_{p}^{(2)}(2, \varphi)\delta_{n, 2}+\psi_{p}^{(-2)}(2)\delta_{n, -2}=-2\sqrt{2\pi}\delta_{n, 0}.
\end{align}
We have in particular
\begin{align}
C_{h, +}^{(0)}+C_{h, -}^{(0)}=&-\frac{5}{2}\sqrt{2\pi},\\
C_{h, +}^{(2)}4+C_{h, -}^{(2)}\frac{1}{4}=&-\frac{[1-4i]\sqrt{2\pi}}{3},\\
C_{h, +}^{(-2)}\frac{1}{4}+C_{h, -}^{(2)}4=&-\frac{[1+4i]\sqrt{2\pi}}{3},\\
C_{h, +}^{(n)}=-C_{h, -}^{(n)}2^{-2n},\quad n\neq0, \ \pm2.
\end{align}
This completes the solution.

Comment: thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are good. I'd like to give my own thoughts.

You can approach this problem in a similar way as I do [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4313457/problem-u-t-u-xx-et-in-mathbbr-times-0-infty/4313583#4313583), by breaking the problem into simpler parts. Your problem is
$$\begin{cases}
(\Delta u)( x,y) =x^{2} +4xy & ( x,y) \in \mathbb{B}( 0,4)\\
u( x,y) =-2 & ( x,y) \in \partial \mathbb{B}( 0,4)
\end{cases}\tag{0}$$
Where $\Delta=\partial_x^2+\partial_y^2$.

I would suggest first finding a solution (call it $u_1$) to
$$\begin{cases}
(\Delta u)( x,y) =x^{2} +4xy & ( x,y) \in \mathbb{B}( 0,4)\\
u( x,y) =0 & ( x,y) \in \partial \mathbb{B}( 0,4)
\end{cases}\tag{1}$$
And then find a solution (call it $u_2$) to
$$\begin{cases}
(\Delta u)( x,y) =0 & ( x,y) \in \mathbb{B}( 0,4)\\
u( x,y) =-2 & ( x,y) \in \partial \mathbb{B}( 0,4)
\end{cases}\tag{2}$$
And then by the linearity of the Laplacian, $u_1+u_2$ will be a solution to $\boldsymbol{(0)}$. What is nice about this approach is that the solution to $\boldsymbol{(2)}$ is already well known. What we can do is make a change of coordinates
$$x'=x/4~~;~~y'=y/4$$
To move the problem to the unit disk, and then use the [Poisson Kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel). Switching to polar coordinates, given the BVP on the unit disk
$$\begin{cases}
(\Delta u)(r,\theta) =0 & r<1\\
u(1,\theta)=h(\theta)& \\
(r,\theta)\in[0,1]\times(-\pi,\pi]
\end{cases}\tag{0}$$
The solution is given by
$$u(r,\theta)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}h(\phi)\frac{1-r^2}{1+r^2+2r\cos(\theta-\phi)}\mathrm d\phi$$
See pages 160-166 in Peter J Olver's [Introduction to Partial Differential Equations](https://www.usb.ac.ir/FileStaff/3223_2019-10-28-13-12-55.pdf) for a derivation of this formula.

So in your case you can pick $h=-2$. Unfortunately I don't think $\boldsymbol{(1)}$ is quite this easy, since $x^2+4xy$ doesn't transform all that nicely under polar coordinates. So perhaps a closed form for this part is not possible. I'm sure the other answers will be plenty useful for this bit.